# Training large data set using OpenNLP

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I have data set with `.train` file and its very large file say 100MB file. I want to perform NER for extracting organization names. I trained using OpenNLP.

Sample Code:

```
TokenNameFinderModel model=NameFinderME.train("en","organization",
              sampleStream,Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
```

But I get an error: `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException`.

Is there any way to train large data set using openNLP for NER? Could you post sample code?

When I Googled I found Class GIS and DataIndexer interface can be used to train large data set but I do know how? Could you post sample code?

Answer (score 2):

I could create models with even larger data without any issue. You probably have a problem with the markup in your .train file. Also, it would help if you could post the complete exception?

For training larger models I simply calibrate cutoff and increase Java memory.

Comment: yes it worked, actually it was problem in my tarin file and now model has been created. and thanks wcolen

Comment: how much time did it take you guys to train your models?  thanks